# Sorting by alphabetical order immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutability, immutable.js

I would like to sort immutable.js orderedList by property `name`,

`data.map(x => x.get("name"))` returns the string, I want to sort my map by name in alphabetical order.

How to do that? I tried:

```
return data.sortBy((val) => {
    if (dir === "up") {
      return val.get("name");
    } else {
      return - val.get("name");
    }
  });
```

Comment: In case someone ever ends up here looking for a way to sort a list or a map by key, here's how: `mapOrList.sortBy((val, key) => key)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
var fiends = Immutable.fromJS([{name: 'Squirrel'}, {name: 'Cat'}, {name: 'Raccoon'}]);
var sorted = fiends.sortBy(
  (f) => f.get('name')
);
sorted.map(x => x.get('name')).toJS();  // ["Cat", "Raccoon", "Squirrel"]
```

With [localCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```
fiends.sort(
  (a, b) => a.get('name').localeCompare(b.get('name'))
);
```

Comment: fiendish animals!

Comment: is sort synchronous?